# What indecency caused the death of Matevilye?

Tags: native-american, mojave

Matevilye, a creator deity of the Mojave, offended his daughter so greatly that she killed him (in a rather bizarre fashion):

> According to the Mohave, the first were the sky, a man, and the earth, a woman. These met far in the west, and from them were born, first Matevilye, and after him his daughter the frog, Mastamho who is usually called his younger brother, all the people, the animals, and plants. All these went upward toward the east, under the leadership of Matevilye. Matevilye himself did not walk. He merely moved four times, twice to the left and twice to the right. Thereby he arrived at Ahavulypo, a narrow defile on the Colorado River above Cottonwood Island, probably near the lower end of Eldorado Canyon. He stretched out his arms to the ends of the world and thereby found this spot to be the centre of the earth. Here he built a house. He became sick because the frog his daughter, whom he had offended by an indecency, ate his excrement; and it was known that he would die.
>
> <sub>Source: Two Myths of the Mission Indians of California. A. L. Kroeber. The Journal of American Folklore Vol. 19, No. 75 (Oct. - Dec., 1906), pp. 309-321</sub>

What was Matevilye's indecency?

Comment: According to this similar story (frog/excrement), the indecency is incest. The pdf is searchable.  https://ia801702.us.archive.org/35/items/jstor-534581/534581.pdf